# Parsing list of different models with Pydantic

Tags: python, pydantic

I am trying to create a pydantic model that can parse json string with a list of different kind of models. See example below

```py
test_object = """
{
  "distributions":
    [
      {
        "param_name": "test1",
        "attributes":
          {
            "distribution_name": "UniformDistribution",
            "low": "1.0",
            "high": "2.0"
          }
      },
      {
        "param_name": "test2",
        "attributes":
          {
            "distribution_name": "UniformDistribution",
            "low": "1.0",
            "high":"2.0"
          }
      },
      {
        "param_name": "test3",
        "attributes":
          {
            "distribution_name": "IntUniformDistribution",
            "low": "1",
            "high": "2",
            "q": 4
          }
      },
      {
        "param_name": "test4",
        "attributes":
          {
            "distribution_name": "DiscreteUniformDistribution",
            "low": "1.0",
            "high": "2.0",
            "step": ".1"
          }
      }
    ]
}
"""
```

This is my `pydantic` model to parse the above string.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, conint, confloat, ValidationError
from typing import List, Literal, Union


class DiscreteUniformDistribution(BaseModel):
    distribution_name: Literal["DiscreteUniformDistribution"]
    low: float
    high: float
    q: confloat(gt=0)

class IntUniformDistribution(BaseModel):
    distribution_name: Literal["IntUniformDistribution"]
    low: int
    high: int
    step: conint(gt=0)

class UniformDistribution(BaseModel):
    distribution_name: Literal["UniformDistribution"]
    low: float
    high: float

class Distribution(BaseModel):
    param_name: str
    attributes: Union[
        DiscreteUniformDistribution,
        IntUniformDistribution,
        UniformDistribution,
    ]

class Distributions(BaseModel):
    distributions: List[Distribution]


try:
    Distributions.parse_raw(test_object)
except ValidationError as e:
    print(e)
```

However I am getting an error

```
9 validation errors for Distributions
distributions -> 2 -> attributes -> distribution_name
  unexpected value; permitted: 'DiscreteUniformDistribution' (type=value_error.const; given=IntUniformDistribution; permitted=('DiscreteUniformDistribution',))
distributions -> 2 -> attributes -> step
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
distributions -> 2 -> attributes -> distribution_name
  unexpected value; permitted: 'UniformDistribution' (type=value_error.const; given=IntUniformDistribution; permitted=('UniformDistribution',))
distributions -> 3 -> attributes -> q
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
distributions -> 3 -> attributes -> distribution_name
  unexpected value; permitted: 'IntUniformDistribution' (type=value_error.const; given=DiscreteUniformDistribution; permitted=('IntUniformDistribution',))
distributions -> 3 -> attributes -> low
  value is not a valid integer (type=type_error.integer)
distributions -> 3 -> attributes -> high
  value is not a valid integer (type=type_error.integer)
distributions -> 3 -> attributes -> step
  value is not a valid integer (type=type_error.integer)
distributions -> 3 -> attributes -> distribution_name
  unexpected value; permitted: 'UniformDistribution' (type=value_error.const; given=DiscreteUniformDistribution; permitted=('UniformDistribution',))
```

If works fine if there is only element in `distributions` list, like shown below.

```
test_object = """
{
  "distributions": 
    [
      {
        "param_name": "test1",
        "attributes":
          {
            "distribution_name": "UniformDistribution",
            "low": "1.0",
            "high": "2.0"
          }
      }
    ]
}
"""
```

I am new to `pydantic`. I suspect the error is do with my improper usage of Union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of `Union[]` looks good, however, there is a typo in your model definitions.

You need to swap `q` in `DiscreteUniformDistribution()` with `step` in `IntUniformDistribution()` (only the field names, not the types), i.e.:

```py
class DiscreteUniformDistribution(BaseModel):
    distribution_name: Literal['DiscreteUniformDistribution']
    low: float
    high: float
    step: confloat(gt=0)
#   ^^^^
#   This is called q in your definition

class IntUniformDistribution(BaseModel):
    distribution_name: Literal['IntUniformDistribution']
    low: int
    high: int
    q: conint(gt=0)
#   ^
#   This is called step in your definition
```